# Trying to map two corrosponding values with different keys in python django

Tags: python, django

in my django project, I am trying to map the following:

In the *views.py*

```
context = {'name': [a, b, c], 'price': [x, y, z], 'date': [1, 2, 3]}

return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

In my *index.html*:

```
{% for value in context %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ value.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ value.price }}</td>
        <td>{{ value.date}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

My target is to get a table in this way:

```
name | price | date
a    |   x   | 1
b    |   y   | 2
c    |   z   | 3
```

I have tried different ways, but so far I have only been able to get one column. I am new to Python. Any help is much apapreicated.

Comment: context is a dict, that is not how you iterate on a dict

Comment: I have tried different ways found in many previous questions in stackoverflow. no luck to achieve desired output. getting one column only, no matter how I tried. I am very new to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this the opposite way: make an iterable (for example a list) of dictionaries, for example with [**`zip(…)`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
data = {'name': [a, b, c], 'price': [x, y, z], 'date': [1, 2, 3]}
new_data = [
    {'name': n, 'price': p, 'date': d}
    for n, p, d in zip(data['name'], data['price'], data['date'])
]

return render(request, 'index.html', {'data': new_data})
```

In the template, you can then render this with:

```
{% for row in data %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.price }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.date }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Output is empty... new_data is not rendered to template?

Comment: @Ahsan: sorry, I made a typo, you pass the `new_data` to the template of course.